# Azure resource deletion locks preventing deletion of role assignment on the resource

Tags: azure, role-based-access-control, azure-role-environment, azure-resource-lock

I have applied deletion lock on my subscription level so that all the resource will get the locks, while revoked the access from virtual machines, azure deletion lock is preventing the IAM role deletion, Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way to fix it - remove the lock, delete the assignment, reestablish the lock. Assignment is really just another resource in the ARM model. nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I was thinking there should be another way, I know that will work if you delete the lock, but it is tedious to do every time

Comment: script it. there is no other way

Comment: i suggest you accept this answer as it clearly answers your question ;)